# How to configure Emmet in Sublime to enable comment shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, key-binding

Since I have enabled Emmet in Sublime 2, some commands don't work properly.

How can I enable what seems to be the default functionality, when in `HTML` file typing

`cmd + /`

in front of

```
<script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

to get the properly commented tag:

```html
<!-- <script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script> -->
```

Right now the same command generates

```
// <script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

which is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that this isn't an issue with Emmet, but with Sublime's built-in HTML language definition. For some reason, it's set up so that any line that starts with a `<script>` tag (optionally with spaces before it) is classified as `source.js.embedded`, meaning that when the comment shortcut is triggered, it uses the JS `//` comment marker instead of the HTML `<!--  -->` one.

The easiest way I found to get around this is to install the [`HTML5`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML5) package via [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io), which I assume you already have installed as you're using Emmet. Install the new package, then open your user preferences (**`Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Settings-User`**) and add `"HTML"` to the `"ignored_packages"` list:

```js
"ignored_packages":
[
    "HTML",
    "Vintage"
],
```

Save the file, and restart Sublime. Now, when you go to **`View -> Syntax`** there should only be one `HTML` entry, but it will refer to the HTML5 syntax, not the built-in one. To test, open the file you were editing above, place your cursor before the `<script>` tag, and hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>. The entire line should now be surrounded in HTML comments:

```html
<!-- <script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script> -->
```

Comment: This is brilliant! I do use Emmet but did not have `HTML5` package, installed it now and it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: A side question - how did you enter the command button so nicely?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev I just do a Google search for "command symbol" and copy it off the results. If you want to have buttons appear in your text, just use `<kbd></kbd>` tags when you're typing. They're only allowed in questions and answers, not comments.